# Is it possible to acquire the workspace path in Xcode 4 via an environment variable

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I can't find anything workspace related in the [Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html).

Essentially I need something like $(WORKSPACE_DIR).  If Xcode doesn't provide it, is there any way to define a custom user variable that could somehow accurately provide the workspace path in the event that the working workspace were to move (think branches etc)?

Comment: SRCROOT provides the path to the current project, not the current workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom variables can be defined under build settings. I think there is a button named Add Build Setting. So, a new variable workspace root can be defined relative to the SRCROOT or use absolute path.

The new setting is shown under "User Defined" group in build settings. "Add Build Setting" button is near lower right corner.

Answer (score 6):

If your workspace is set up like:

```
//bla/bla/bla/workspace/{project directories}*
```

then you can use

```
$(SRCROOT)/../
```

to get the workspace directory from a give project directory.

---

For example, if you want to have one project reference headers in another project:

> Project Build Settings->User Header Search Paths =>
>   $(SRCROOT)/../SomeLibProj

(and set it to 'recursive' if you don't want to add every folder)

Comment: This has helped me when `Carthage` folder was at the workspace's root

Comment: this only works for the specific target. What if you want to reach to a different target?