# Xcode - How to share workspace settings with others?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a workspace and I set the derived data location to a workspace relative path in order to simplify some other operations.

But I found that the workspace settings is stored in the xcuserdata, and can't be shared. This will lead to failures of some of my scripts in Jenkins.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following screenshot.
[image]

You can find that dialog box at "Manage Schemes...".
Then check 'Shared' checkbox.

Comment: I'd like to have all my projects' derived location set to a workspace-relative path, so I set this in `File > Workspace Settings`. Is there any way to share this settings with others?

Comment: @WakoM I see. I don't know if there is an build setting variable as `SRCROOT` for a project or not. I expect that the following link would be helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8659365/579236)